# (Why) Does Windows "Calc.exe" lack a WndProc?

Tags: c, vb.net, windows, winapi, spy++

I am fiddling with wndprocs and WinSpy++ and i stumbled upon a strange thing with calc.exe.
 It appears to lack a WndProc.

Here is my screenshot: a test program I made, the WinSpy++ window,, showing N/A, and the culprit.

[image: A test program I made, the Winspy window, showing N/A, and the culprit.]

Maybe the tool is a bit outdated, but the empirical evidence proves no WndProc is there.

I don't know if this is  by design(this would be strange), or if I am missing something...

Here is referenced code:

```
Function FindWindow(title As String) As IntPtr
    Return AutoIt.AutoItX.WinGetHandle(title)
End Function

Function GetWindowProc(handle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Return GetWindowLong(handle, WindowLongFlags.GWL_WNDPROC)
End Function
```

Comment: Which WinSpy version are you using? It looks pretty updated and it may not (but I'm guessing!!!) _understand_ an Unicode WndProc (wrongly thinking there is not)

Comment: I checked the Catch22 website and I'm using the last version released, which is v 1.7 (1.7.1 in the about...).

Also I am on Windows 7 x64, if that can help.

Comment: 1.7.1? I just checked VS2k12 and its Spy++ version is **11.0**

Comment: I checked here: http://www.catch22.net/software
I am using **Win**Spy++, not *Microsoft* Spy++

Comment: No it's not by design and it's not even possible; **every** window has a window procedure. You may not supply one but Windows will provide default one. Problem is just in the tool you're using...

Comment: There must be some (not obvious to me) problem also in the code I used to check this.

Comment: You made a simple mistake, run the 64-bit version of Spy++ instead.  So it can display info from 64-bit processes, like Calc.exe.  You'll find it in Common7\Tools\spyxx_amd64.exe"

Comment: @HansPassant no, WinSpy++ is 32 bit only. Also on 32 bit Calc (of course on 32 bit Windows) it doesn't work. Actually it doesn't _read_ window procedure address of many windows, not just calc.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short (about your code): `GetWindowLong()` fails because you're trying to read an address in target process address space.

**EXPLANATION**

When `GetWindowLong()` returns 0 it means there is an **error**, from MSDN:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Check `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and you probably see error code is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (numeric value is 0x5).

Why? Because `GetWindowLong()` is trying to get address (or handle) of window procedure (not in your code, but in **target process**, in theory it may even be default window procedure but I never saw an application main window that doesn't hanle at least few messages). You may use this trick (but I never tried!) to see if a window is using default procedure (you have an address or not), I don't know...someone should try.

Now think what `WNDPROC` is:

```
LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC) (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

An address (valid in process A) is not callable in process B (where it makes no sense at all). Windows DLLs code segments are shared across processes (I assume, I didn't check but it's reasonable in the game between safety and performance).

Moreover `CallWindowProc(NULL, ...)` will understand that `NULL` as a special value to invoke window procedure for that window class (on `HWND` owner). From MSDN:

> ...If this value is obtained by calling the GetWindowLong function ...the address of a window or dialog box procedure, or a special internal value meaningful only to CallWindowProc.

How Microsoft Spy++ does it (and maybe WinSpy++ does not)? Hard to say without WinSpy++ source code. For sure it's not such easy like `GetWindowLong()` and *right* way should involve `CreateRemoteThread()` and to do `LoadLibrary()` from that but both Microsoft Spy++ and WinSpy++ source code aren't available (AFAIK) for further inspection...

**UPDATE**

WinSpy++ inspection/debugging is pretty off-topic with the question (you should post a ticket to developers, **your** source code may fail for what I explained above, you should - **always** - check error codes) but we may take a look for fun.

In `InjectThread.c` we see it uses `WriteProcessMemory` + `CreateRemoteThread` then `ReadProcessMemory` to read data back (not relevant code omitted):

```
// Write a copy of our injection thread into the remote process
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pdwRemoteCode, lpCode, cbCodeSize, &dwWritten);

// Write a copy of the INJTHREAD to the remote process. This structure
// MUST start on a 32bit boundary
pRemoteData = (void *)((BYTE *)pdwRemoteCode + ((cbCodeSize + 4) & ~ 3));

// Put DATA in the remote thread's memory block
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteData, lpData, cbDataSize, &dwWritten);

hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, 
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)pdwRemoteCode, pRemoteData, 0, &dwRemoteThreadId);

// Wait for the thread to terminate
WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);

// Read the user-structure back again
if(!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteData, lpData, cbDataSize, &dwRead))
{
    //an error occurred
}
```

Window procedure in "General" tab and in "Class" tab differs (in "Class" tab it correctly display a value). From `DisplayClassInfo.c`:

```
//window procedure
if(spy_WndProc == 0)    
{
    wsprintf(ach, _T("N/A"));
}
else                    
{
    wsprintf(ach, szHexFmt, spy_WndProc);
    if(spy_WndProc != spy_WndClassEx.lpfnWndProc)
        lstrcat(ach, _T(" (Subclassed)"));
}

//class window procedure
if(spy_WndClassEx.lpfnWndProc == 0)
    wsprintf(ach, _T("N/A"));
else
    wsprintf(ach, szHexFmt, spy_WndClassEx.lpfnWndProc);
```

As you see they're different values (obtained in different ways). Code to fill `spy_WndProc` is in `WinSpy.c` and `GetRemoteWindowInfo.c`. Extracted code from `GetRemoteInfo()` in `WinSpy.c`:

```
GetClassInfoEx(0, spy_szClassName, &spy_WndClassEx);
GetRemoteWindowInfo(hwnd, &spy_WndClassEx, &spy_WndProc, spy_szPassword, 200);
```

Now in `GetRemoteWindowInfo()` we see a call to `GetClassInfoExProc` (injected in the other process):

```
pInjData->wndproc = (WNDPROC)pInjData->fnGetWindowLong(pInjData->hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
pInjData->fnGetClassInfoEx(pInjData->hInst,
    (LPTSTR)pInjData->szClassName, &pInjData->wcOutput);
```

As you can see (please follow using source code) `wcOutput` is what is displayed in "Class" tab and `wndproc` what is displayed in "General" tab. Simply `GetWindowLong()` fails but `GetClassInfoEx` does not (but they do not necessarily retrieve same value because (if I'm not wrong) what you have in `WNDCLASSEX` is what you registered with `RegisterClassEx` but what you get with `GetWindowLong()` is what you hooked with `SetWindowLong()`.

Comment: This would make sense, except that before I posted my answer, I did verify that Microsoft Spy++ was able to obtain the window procedure for multiple windows of other programs, yet not of that of calc.exe.

Comment: @hvd it's a weird behavior but it's hard to say where the **WinSpy++ bug** is without WinSpy++ source code. For sure calc.exe does not rely only on default window procedure (open 1st instance: address A, open 2nd instance: address A again, close them all and try again and you'll have another address). That "0" for CallWindowProc() works locally, I would guess it's CreateRemoteThread() and LoadLibrary() but I don't see ms spy++ nor winspy++ source code.

Comment: Microsoft Spy++ is giving the same results for me as WinSpy++ in the OP's screenshot: it doesn't give any address, so I don't see how I could use your approach to compare addresses.

Comment: Yet Hans Passant (as usual) does manage to clear up the real problem with his comment on the question.

Comment: Microsoft Spy++ is working for me (and I'm testing on Windows localized in Italian as OP).

Comment: @hvd no, I just downloaded and installed WinSpy++ and no, it doesn't work also on 32 bit Windows (with 32 bit calc.exe). BTW it doesn't display window procedure in first tab but it correctly display that value in the "Class" tab.

Comment: I didn't know about the process space restrictions... I checked MS Spy++ (x64) and it is able to read the WndProc address of Calculator(x64).

Maybe it is time to dump WinSpy++ for these things and keep it just for UI fiddling.


I've also checked with a `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`in my code after the call and it returns 0 (Operation_COMPLETE) and not 5.

So said I'm going trough the path of Dll Injection.

Comment: @beppe9000 also WinSpy uses code injection so it _should_ work (of course on 32 bit processes) but it doesn't. You may download its source code and add some serious error checking. I didn't see any doc about GetWindowLong(...) that may return 0 (to default to what specified in WNDCLASSEX) but it also may be. In case you further investigate please share your results here!

Comment: @beppe9000 I forget: do not forget to include SetLastError=True in DllImportAttribute for GetWindowLong! According to MSDN GetWindowLong() will return 0 instead of WndProc address/handle _only_ in case of error.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks. Sadly i am not skilled enough to improve WinSpy.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It does not have a WndProc(...) function. It is just simply using a DlgProc to process the dialog events. I now this as I have written 'server/thin client' code in C/C++ to capture direct calls into windows API functions like WndProc(...). Any Windows GUI function really - BeginPaint(...) as an example. I used CALC.EXE as a test and executable runs on server while GUI calls are relayed/returned to/from the thin client. Have only tested calc.exe versions thru Vista. There is a chance the newer versions have been 'programmed' differently - meaning not using Win32 SDK. But, even MFC is just a shell to the Win32 SDK,